# Microservice deployment using AWS ECS service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I am trying to creating a microservice using spring boot and trying to deploy using AWS ECS cloud service. I Have doubts in deployment using ECS. In ECS there is a facility of EC2 launch type.

Here my doubt is that, when I am using ECS EC2 launch type, can I choose my own Ubuntu machine instances? I need to know whether the ECS provide provision to launch with my own Ubuntu machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use your own Ubuntu AMI, but it requires a little bit of work. Here are the [requirements](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/container_instance_AMIs.html):

> A modern Linux distribution running at least version 3.10 of the Linux kernel.
>
> The Amazon ECS container agent (preferably the latest version). For more information, see Amazon ECS Container Agent.
>
> A Docker daemon running at least version 1.5.0, and any Docker runtime dependencies. For more information, see Check runtime dependencies in the Docker documentation.

So, apart from installing Docker, you need o install and configure the ECS Agent. You will find the instructions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-agent-install.html). See section 'To install the Amazon ECS container agent on a non-Amazon Linux EC2 instance'

Once you have your AMI built, you just [create your cluster](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/create_cluster.html) and then [launch the instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/launch_container_instance.html) into it.

Comment: Ok. I got the concept. Thank you for your response and spending time with my confusion.Thanks.